# Learning COMPUTED BY - what right parenthesis does it need?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, errors, computed-column

I am reading this document on [Automatic columns](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/rdb/automatic-columns-132042.pdf).

The first snippet in it creates a `COMPUTED BY` column:

```
create table PERSON (
(employee_id integer,
employee_id_disp computed by
SUBSTRING (CAST(employee_id + 100000 as VARCHAR (6)) from 2)
);
```

When I run this snippet, I get this error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
create table PERSON (
(employee_id integer,
employee_id_disp computed by
SUBSTRING (CAST(employee_id + 100000 as VARCHAR (6)) from 2)
)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

And whey I try to create my own table as follows:

```
create table A (
  a1 varchar(4000) not null,
  a1Raw computed by UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(a1)
)
```

I get a different error:

```
Error starting at line : 11 in command -
create table A (
  a1 varchar(4000) not null,
  a1Raw computed by UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(a1)
)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I am not overly concerned about the snippet from the Oracle's PDF not working: it sometimes happens that documentation contains bugs. But why is my script not working? I cannot see where a right parenthesis may be possibly missing because all of them match.

Answer (score 1):

Forget `COMPUTED BY` and just use `AS` which is the same as `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ... VIRTUAL`

Syntax summary is [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6).

There is no `computed by` clause and there never has been. OP was looking in the manuals for something called [Oracle RDB](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/related/rdb.html) that runs on [OpenVMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) and nobody uses.